How to have a sticky element that stops before end of viewport
I have a headline and a thead that need to be sticky, but they shouldn't stay sticky when the last row comes up. Instead, they should stop being sticky so that the last row of the tbody is always visible and is the last element that scrolls away.
I have tried to separate the headline and the thead from the tbody.
But i coudn't find a way to let the headline/thead div to stop before the last row.
Edit:
I have found a way to maintain the spacing.
With a margin-botom with the height of the last line, but I have to find a way to set the margin only when the table body is scrolled, so that there is no space between the header and the first line.


            $(".myTable").each(function () {
                var lastRowOuterHeight = $(this).find('.tableBody tr:last').outerHeight();

                if (true) {// todo how to detect if table body is scrolled?
                    var stickyTable =  $(this).find('.stickyHeader');
                    stickyTable.attr('style', 'margin-bottom: ' + lastRowOuterHeight + 'px !important;');
                }
         
            });
    body {
      height: 1000px;
    }

    .table tbody td {
      min-width: 6rem;
      max-width: 6rem;
    }

    .table th {
      min-width: 6rem;
      max-width: 6rem;
    }

    .stickyHeader {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      background: #f5f5f5;
    }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="myTable pb-4 ">
        <div class=" stickyHeader mb-0" >
            <h4 class="pb-1 ">My headline</h4>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="tableHeader table table-sm table-bordered border-dark  mb-0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="tableBody  table table-responsive table-sm table-bordered border-dark mb-0">
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                       
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                        </tr>

                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>




"but I have to find a way to set the margin only when the table body is scrolled" - what actually "gets scrolled" here, is the document itself. So you will need to add a window scroll event handler for that first of all. And then you will have to look at the offsetTop of your headline and your table body, and based on those values figure out, whether the scrolling has actually make the sticky positioning "kick in" or not.

(And you are aware, that because you split this up into two separate tables, the columns on top don't follow those in the body any more, if you are scrolling on the other axis, yes? So that you'll also have to fix via additional JS.)

@C3roe thx for the tips. I've found a easy solution (see answers) to synconise the scrolling I've some JS but I wanted to keep the code clean. -> See Here

I've found a solution:
get the outerHeiht of the last Row = lastRowHeight
get the height of the scrollbar
add a margin-bottom lastRowOuterHeight + scrollBarHeight on stickyHeader
add a margin-top lastRowOuterHeight - scrollBarHeight  on tableBodySection


    $(".myTable").each(function () {
       var lastRowHeight = $(this).find('.tableBody tr:last').outerHeight();
         var tableBody = $(this).find('.tableBody')[0];
       var stickyTableBottom = $(this).find('.stickyHeader');
       var stickyTableTop = $(this).find('.tableBodySection');
       
       var scrollBarHeight = tableBody.offsetHeight - tableBody.clientHeight;
       
       // .css() cannot use !important Attention: .attr() overwrites all other inLine styles  
       stickyTableBottom.attr('style', 'margin-bottom: ' + (lastRowHeight + scrollBarHeight) + 'px !important;');
       stickyTableTop.attr('style', 'margin-top: -' + (lastRowHeight + scrollBarHeight) + 'px !important;');
    });
    body {
      height: 1000px;
    }

    .table tbody td {
      min-width: 6rem;
      max-width: 6rem;
    }

    .table th {
      min-width: 6rem;
      max-width: 6rem;
    }

    .stickyHeader {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 2;
      background: #f5f5f5;
    }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="myTable pb-4 ">
        <div class=" stickyHeader mb-0" >
            <h4 class="pb-1 ">My headline</h4>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="tableHeader table table-sm table-bordered border-dark  mb-0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                                <th>Col</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tableBodySection table-responsive">
            <table class="tableBody  table table-responsive table-sm table-bordered border-dark mb-0">
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                            <td > Content </td>
                        </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
    </body>




To synchronise the vertical scroll I've used this code in my project -> see here
